# MariaDB execute UPDATE and then DELETE if condition is true

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, mariadb

I'm writing a Node JS app and need to execute `UPDATE` and `DELETE` queries in the same statement, but `DELETE` should be executed in another table and only if the condition equals a certain state.
I'm not sure about my syntex... Here is what I have so far:

```
UPDATE vm_log SET user_id_fk = (SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE username = ?), vm_state = ? WHERE vm_id = ?;
SET @vmState = ?;
IF @vmState = 'PERMANENT' THEN
DELETE FROM vm_ext_tracking WHERE vm_fk = ?;
END IF
```

Where `?` are supplied as paramaters. For example `username = 'someUser'`, `vm_state = 'ACTIVE'` or `PERMANENT`, and vm_id some number: `vm_id = 4303`.
The `UPDATE` part works fine separately, just need to add a layer of complexity with `DELETE`.
The error message I receive:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @vmState = 'PERMANENT' THEN
DELETE FROM vm_ext_tracking WHERE vm_fk = 4303' at line 1
```

Comment: missing opening `'` for `'4304'`

Comment: if `vm_fk` is a integer column it does not need to be wrapped in quotes.

Comment: it is a number - no quotes needed

Comment: yeah agree, wasn't sure what the specifics were for having an int quote.

Comment: it is error message, not my SQL statement. Error is stating: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @vmState = 'PERMANENT' THEN
DELETE FROM vm_ext_tracking WHERE vm_fk = 4303'

Comment: the error is the SQL statement (syntax error specifically).

Comment: Last I checked, you cannot use procedural logic, such as that form of `IF`, outside of stored procedures and functions in MySQL. _Also, what you have presented is not a single "statement" to SQL; I'm not sure about node.js, but many APIs would require those to be sent in separate "execute"/"query" calls._

Comment: I have no problem to run another/separate query for "DELETE", but it will make more sense to run them together

Comment: You can not use this in a mysql command, this is only possible if you ose your query in a **PROCEDURE**

Comment: A `TRIGGER` might be called for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE vm_log 
SET user_id_fk = ( SELECT user_id 
                   FROM users 
                   WHERE username = ?), 
    vm_state = ? 
WHERE vm_id = ?;

SET @vmState = ?;

DELETE 
FROM vm_ext_tracking 
WHERE vm_fk = ?
  AND @vmState = 'PERMANENT';
```

PS. `@vmState` is excess, if you do not need in it in the below (not shown) code you may use

```
UPDATE vm_log 
SET user_id_fk = ( SELECT user_id 
                   FROM users 
                   WHERE username = ?), 
    vm_state = ? 
WHERE vm_id = ?;

DELETE 
FROM vm_ext_tracking 
WHERE ? = 'PERMANENT'
  AND vm_fk = ?;
```

Comment: You may want to put them between `BEGIN` and `COMMIT`.